# Adding a tag to a JQuery object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically create objects using JQuery. I have a json object with elements I want to pull and add onto the object. So far I've been using this line and I am getting text on my object:

```
$(this.node).find('a').text(dict.get('text1'));
```

I want to add a second object, "text2", with a paragraph tag. What is the function to add tags to a jquery object in a similar manner to how I've been adding text?

Edit: I want to end up with an object that has two paragraph tags which I can add class/id tags to

Comment: .append() is what you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't `data` what you're looking for: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: For append, the problem is that old text is retained when new text is added. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: What is your exact need? can you just explain with sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `.append()` function:

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

If you want to add a paragraph, you can do this:

```
var $p = $("p");
$p.text("This will be the paragraph text.");
$(".container").append($p);
```

Also here you find the [**insertion-inside**](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) functions.

Comment: For append, the problem is that old text is retained when new text is added. Is there anyway around that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options depending on how/where you want to insert your tags relative to existing content: [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or appendTo(), [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or insertAfter(), [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or insertBefore(). If you are inserting multiple tags in the same area, you also can 'concatenate' them first using these functions, before actually inserting it to your larger jQuery object.